# 5part css image, where am i going wrong

Tags: css

```
background-image: url({style_images_url}/maintitle_right.png), url({style_images_url}/maintitleleft.png), url({style_images_url}/maintitlecenter.png), url({style_images_url}/repeatingtitle.png, url({style_images_url}/repeatingtitle.png;

background-position: right, left, center, right, left;
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x, repeat-x;
```

Basically im trying to create a 5 part image, the left right and center, and then two of the same images repeating between them, can anyon tell me where im going wrong?

Comment: Before we tell you what you are doing wrong, can you tell us what exactly happens?

Comment: Besides, you are missing `)` in last few `url:()`.

Comment: Hi yes i realise, the center image isnt displaying.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/64vz0t7j/